# take some data out of an xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml, treelist

I have an xml  with the next structure:

```
<main>
   <students>
      <student>
           <name> John </name>
           <phone> 123 </phone>
           <courses>
                  <course>
                       <mark> 5 </mark>
                        <room> 11D </room> 
                        <name> Math </name>
                  </course>
                  <course>
                       <mark> 8 </mark>
                        <room> 12a </room> 
                        <name> Literature </name>
                  </course>
           </courses>
      </student>

      <student>
           <name> Terry </name>
           <phone> 332 </phone>
           <courses>
                  <course>
                       <mark> 9 </mark>
                        <room> 12D </room> 
                        <name> Math </name>
                  </course>
                  <course>
                       <mark> 4 </mark>
                        <room> 2a </room> 
                        <name> Literature </name>
                  </course>
           </courses>
      </student>
   </students>

   <profs>
   ....
   </profs>
</main>
```

How can I get the information in this format:

John ->  math, 5; literature, 8
Terry -> math, 9; literature, 4

What I want to do is to create a tree list like this:

John
  |**_** Math - 5
  |**_** Literature - 8
Terry
  |**_** Math - 9
  |**_** Literature - 4

I manage it to extract the names of the students and to put them as nodes in the treelist.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the XElement class
Have a look at this [example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/xLinkDoc06202007130827PM/xLinkDoc.aspx)

You can iterate through nodes or even define linq queries to this:

```
        XElement allData = XElement.Load("Authors.xml"); 
        if (allData != null) 
        { 
            IEnumerable<XElement> authors = allData.Descendants("Author"); 
            foreach(XElement author in authors) 
                Console.WriteLine((string)author); 
        }
```

And have a look at this [example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/xelement):

```
    string t = "Some title";
    var v = from page in _x.Elements("SitePage")
        where t == page.Element("Title").Value
        select page;
```

Comment: Sorry hit accidentially the save button and didnt attached example and link. 
Example and link don't look good as comment...

Answer (score 1):

Okay so what you want is essentially a dictionary holding a string and another dictionary holding a string and a list.

```
var xml = XElement.Parse("");
var students = xml.Descendants("student");

students.ToDictionary(x => x.Element("name").Value,
    x => x.Descendants("course")
        .ToDictionary(y => y.Element("name").Value,
            y => int.Parse(y.Element("mark").Value)));
```

This creates a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>` where the first key is your student's name, and the second is a dictionary of course names and marks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var allData = XElement.Parse("");
var query = from student in allData.Descendants("student")
            let name = student.Element("name").Value
            select new {
                        StudentName = name , 
                        Courses = 
                                 (from course in student.Descendants("course")
                                  let mark = course.Element("mark").Value
                                  let courseName = course.Element("name").Value
                                  select new { 
                                          CourseName = courseName , 
                                          Mark = mark }
                                  )
                         };
```

you may need to check for null values.
I know this is not very easy debug.

**[Edit]** 
`allData.Descendants("student")` with `"student"` not in uppercase.

test :

```
foreach (var student in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(student.StudentName);
    foreach (var course in student.Courses)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(" - {0} => {1}", course.CourseName, course.Mark));
    }
}
```